# Chrome flickering on -webkit-filter: blur

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm applying a blur transition to the body of my page

```
body
    transition(all 1s)
    &.blurred
        pointer-events none
        transition(all 1s)
        -webkit-filter blur(5px)
```

Chrome flickers when I add the blurred class to body, whereas Safari does not.

http://jsfiddle.net/j89Zs/

Adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` does not solve this. It seems to eliminate the first flicker, but Chrome keeps flickering after the blur is applied, especially if body contains a lot of content/divs.

Is there any way to achieve the same effect, without the flickering?

Comment: Sadly, there isn't much we can do about Chrome's terrible rendering issues. I wish they'd take the time to get things right before releasing new features...

Comment: I'm not seeing the flickering.  It does a smooth transition from normal to a blur.  Specific version of Chrome?  Desktop version?

Comment: Just started seeing this as well (Stable 34.0.1847.137) Things look better in Canary 37.0.2002.0 using backface visibility: hidden

Answer (score 7):

I'm not seeing the flicker (Chrome 35.0 on OSX Mavericks) but I find the following often works for solving animation flickering in webkit:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question but still for someone who would land here with the same problem: After hours of searching finally realized chrome is got such problems. The closest solution I found was to apply:

filter:blur(0.3px);

Lower the pixel anymore(tried 0, 0.1 and 0.2) and it goes blank.

This will slightly lower the clarity but to a very minimal/unnoticeable Level(much better than the flicker).

Answer (score 0):

The flickering is still there on *MacOS Mojave 10.14* in *Chrome*, in case filter property is applied to an element.

Setting [backface visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility) to hidden, on the same element, solves the issue:

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
```