# Css blur not working well with iframe content

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I have a portfolio site here:

http://benliger.webatu.com/

i had added a blur effect when you hover over the header so that it blurs out the content in all the body containers. It seems to work fine on all pages apart from the one entitled music. When you bring up the music content and move the mouse quickly over the header section then out, the iframes (the soundcloud song ones) seems to move right out of their container to the top left of the page

Is there a way to fix this? Only started happening when i added a css transition to the blur. Also the effect does not work on firefox even when using the -moz webkit...

Here is the code:

Div that is added to the container to make it blur out

```
.elementhovered {
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;

}
```

Jquery function to insert blur (element hovered class)

```
$(".header").hover(
  function () {
        $('.homecontainer,.aboutcontainer,.contactcontainer,.musiccontainer,.portfoliocontainer,.backgroundimage').addClass('elementhovered').addClass('elementhovered');
  }, 
  function () {
    $('.homecontainer,.aboutcontainer,.contactcontainer,.musiccontainer,.portfoliocontainer,.backgroundimage').removeClass('elementhovered').removeClass('elementhovered');
```

}
      );

Thanks,
Be

Comment: You should post essential part of code here. Also, it is a good idea to create [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with this part of code. Even though I remember your site :)

Comment: Added above in edits :)

Comment: What for do you add and remove same class twice?

Comment: I thought you had to to as the structure of .hover is .hover( handlerIn, handlerOut ) correct?

Comment: I mean `.addClass('elementhovered').addClass('elementhovered')`

Comment: oh right thats a mistake, let me remove that now :)

Comment: Well, I still can't understand why it moves... Maybe it's a bug in browser. All I can suggest is to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619520/chrome-flickering-on-webkit-filter-blur) or to remove class only when blur animation is done (for example, wrapping `.removeClass()` with `setTimeout(function(){}, 500)`),

Comment: Yea must be a bug. I tried your suggestions by adding the following: setTimeout(function () {.removeClass('elementhovered');}, 500); but it seems to have broken my code

Comment: I didn't mean it literally so :) I mean `setTimeout(function () { $('.homecontainer,.aboutcontainer,.contactcontainer,.musiccontainer,.portfoliocontainer,.backgroundimage').removeClass('elementhovered'); }, 500);` inside hover out function.

Comment: Sorry, still learning :). I tried your latest code but it doesn't want to come out of the blur now, could you take a look? Amended code is live atm

Comment: I've found a related article here that seems to have fixed it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619520/chrome-flickering-on-webkit-filter-blur?lq=1. It looks like adding in -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000; ensures a smoother transition

Comment: I have actually suggested this link to you in comments above :) So  problem is solved?

Comment: Ahh you did too! sorry missed the hyperlink. Thanks for your help!